# mysql запись в таблицу

Tags: python, pymysql

Можно ли записать в таблицу mysql вот также, мне нужно информацию отображать в ввиде текста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Различайте хранение данных и клиентское отображение этих данных. Создать показанный вид - задача отображения, выполняемая соответствующей подсистемой на клиенте. Хотя её и можно решить на сервере, скомпоновав данные из нескольких нормализованных таблиц требуемым образом - но нецелесообразно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли записать в таблицу mysql вот также?

Нет, реляционная модель не позволит её нарушать

Comment: а куда такое можно записать помимо Excell на сервере?

Comment: @Vadim на ум приходит только таблица у которой один из столбцов для бинарных данных(VARBINARY) - в него скидывать. Или попытаться конвертировать это в XML и создать таблицу со столбцом типа XML

Comment: Как выше уже заметили, Вы можете сохранить данные в таблице, а вывод уже оформить!!! Проанализируйте Ваши данные и подумайте какие данные изменяются и как будут использоваться...сохранить в mysql можно все..а вот как будут отображаться и связаны данные зависит от Вас

Comment: Присоединяюсь к Akina и Pavlo Khyzhniak. Если возникла необходимость сохранять такие данные в реляционной базе, то стоит пересмотреть ТЗ. Абсолютно бесполезно использовать базу для хранения этого(разве что в бинарном формате и работать из базы с этим файлом никто не будет).